# Bootstrapping after training_test split or original dataset?

Tags: python, resampling

My dataset contains 1000 sets which I'm using it for the classification problem. I used LR and SVM as a machine learning algorithm. I was wondering if I should use Bootstrapping from training set and then apply LR & SVM or use Bootstrapping from original dataset? When I look at the accuracy score, I shouldn't use bootstrapping from original dataset.

Comment: Please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrapping from the original dataset defeats the purpose of having the two different datasets (train/test). You always train the model on the training dataset and calculate the accuracy or another score on the test dataset.

If you bootstrap from the original dataset, you'll be training your model on (a subset of) the whole dataset, which will include a part of the test dataset, so your resulting metrics (that you'll calculate based on the test dataset) will be biased because you trained the model on part of the *test* dataset.

Comment: that's also what i thought as well, because that's not the whole purpose of bootstrapping. So I have to do bootstrapping from the training set right?

Comment: @Mike, yes, I think so

Comment: There is also a different interpretation of bootstrapping here: https://thinkingneuron.com/how-to-test-machine-learning-models-using-bootstrapping/ there bootstrapping is interpreted as making the statistic on multiple rounds of test-splitting the original dataset after random shuffle, train the model and calculate its accuracy - no resampling with replacement is found in that code.